# Pandas dataframe deduplicate rows with column logic

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with about 100 million rows. I am interested in deduplicating it but have some criteria that I haven't been able to find documentation for.

I would like to deduplicate the dataframe, ignoring one column that will differ. If that row is a duplicate, except for that column, I would like to only keep the row that has a specific string, say `X`.

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A","B","C"],
                  data = [[1,2,"00X"],
                          [1,3,"010"],
                          [1,2,"002"]])
```

Desired output:

```
>>> df_dedup

   A  B    C
0  1  2  00X
1  1  3  010
```

So, alternatively stated, the row index 2 would be removed because row index 0 has the information in columns `A` and `B`, and `X` in column `C`

As this data is slightly large, I hope to avoid iterating over rows, if possible. [Ignore Index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) is the closest thing I've found to the built-in `drop_duplicates()`.

If there is no `X` in column `C` then the row should require that `C` is identical to be deduplicated.

In the case in which there are matching `A` and `B` in a row, but have multiple versions of having an `X` in `C`, the following would be expected.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C"],
                  data = [[1,2,"0X0"],
                          [1,2,"X00"],
                          [1,2,"0X0"]])
```

Output should be:

```
>>> df_dedup

   A  B    C
0  1  2  0X0
1  1  2  X00
```

Comment: What if there is no string `X` in column `C` in any of the rows where `A` and `B` are duplicated?

Comment: Then I would want `C` to be part of the deduplication criteria. Thank you for the clarification, adding to the question.

Comment: Can there be multiple rows with `X` for the same `A` and `B`, and whats the expected output in such case?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple rows  with `X` in `C` for the same `A` and `B`. See the updated question for such output. Thanks again for helping me write it more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) on columns `A and B` to create a boolean mask `m1` corresponding to condition where values in column `A` and `B` are not duplicated, then use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) + [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) on column `C` to create a boolean mask corresponding to condition where `C` contains string `X` and `C` is not duplicated. Finally using these masks filter the rows in `df`.

```
m1 = ~df[['A', 'B']].duplicated()
m2 = df['C'].str.contains('X') & ~df['C'].duplicated()
df = df[m1 | m2]
```

Result:

```
#1
   A  B    C
0  1  2  00X
1  1  3  010

#2
   A  B    C
0  1  2  0X0
1  1  2  X00
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the column "C" always have X as the last character of each value? You could try creating a column D with 1 if column C has an X or 0 if it does not. Then just sort the values using sort_values and finally use drop_duplicates with keep='last'

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["A","B","C"],
                  data = [[1,2,"00X"],
                          [1,3,"010"],
                          [1,2,"002"]])

df['D'] = 0
df.loc[df['C'].str[-1] == 'X', 'D'] = 1
df.sort_values(by=['D'], inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep='last', inplace=True)
```

This is assuming you also want to drop duplicates in case there is no X in the 'C' column among the duplicates of columns A and B

Comment: The `X` will not always be the last character but I do like the response and I believe that will help me get to a solid enough result. Simpler than I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.  I left 'count' (a helper column) in for transparency.

```
# use df as defined above

# count the A,B pairs
df['count'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).transform('count').squeeze()

m1 = (df['count'] == 1)
m2 = (df['count'] > 1)  & df['C'].str.contains('X') # could be .endswith('X')

print(df.loc[m1 | m2])  # apply masks m1, m2

   A  B    C  count
0  1  2  00X      2
1  1  3  010      1
```